# Query isn't giving decimals on java, but it gives decimals on database

Tags: java, mysql, decimal

I have a query that when I execute it on database, it gives me decimals, but when I execute the same query on my app, it gives me the numbers without decimals.

I have my variables setted as "double" and they are correctly "linked" to the database, I put the code below.

Here is where I call the method:

```
        List<DatosEstadistica> listaDatosEstadistica = facade.obtenerDatosIngresos(filtro);
```

The facade:

```
 public List<DatosEstadistica> obtenerDatosIngresos(FiltroInformes filtro)
            throws ServiceException {
        return this.modeloService.obtenerDatosIngresos(filtro);
    }
```

The service implement:

```
 public List<DatosEstadistica> obtenerDatosIngresos(FiltroInformes filtro)
        throws ServiceException {

    try {

        return this.getDao().obtenerDatosIngresos(filtro);

    } catch (HibernateException he) {

        throw new ServiceException(he);
    }

}
```

And the query instructions:

```
 public List<DatosEstadistica> obtenerDatosIngresos(FiltroInformes filtro) {

    try {
        StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
        query.append("sum( decode ( a.indingdev,'R',0, "
                + "nvl(a.impingdev,0) + "
                + "nvl(a.imprecargo_ing,0) "
                + ")       "
                + ") as total_recaudado, "                   
                + "from tableM m, table_f f, table_a a "
                + "where m.reg = f.reg");
               
            
        SQLQuery querySQL = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery(query.toString());

        querySQL.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DatosEstadistica.class));

        return querySQL.list();
    } catch (HibernateException qe) {
        throw qe;
    }
}
```

And datosEstadistica.class:

```
public class DatosEstadistica implements Serializable {

/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 88592689034562323954L;


private double TOTAL_RECAUDADO;


/**
 * Instantiates a new datos estadistica.
 */
public DatosEstadistica() {
    
}

public double getTOTAL_RECAUDADO() {
    return TOTAL_RECAUDADO;
}

public void setTOTAL_RECAUDADO(double tOTAL_RECAUDADO) {
    TOTAL_RECAUDADO = tOTAL_RECAUDADO;
}

}
```

But I don't know why it doesn't give me decimals as in the same query executed on the database. Anyone can helps me, please?

EDIT:

Here is where I printed out the results, but it doesn't print the decimals, because the query List "listDatosEstadistica" return numbers without decimals:

```
   celdaDatos.setCellValue((listaDatosEstadistica.get(i).getTOTAL_RECAUDADO()));
```

Comment: where are you printing out?

Comment: answered with the printing out @ScaryWombat

Comment: so the problem could be with `setCellValue` - is it formatted for floating point?

Comment: I don't think so, the list that I use to print the values on the excel returns "380.0", and when I execute the same query in database, it returns "380.5", so I think the problem is happening before the moment I print the value